# parse error when trying to display in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error whenever I'm trying to display items from database in my views.

> Undefined variable: manufacturer (View:.../index.blade.php)

in my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $title = array('pageTitle' => Lang::get("website.Home"));
    $result = array();  

    $manufacturers = DB::table('manufacturers')
    ->leftJoin('manufacturers_info','manufacturers_info.manufacturers_id', '=', 'manufacturers.manufacturers_id')
    ->select('manufacturers.manufacturers_id as id', 'manufacturers.manufacturers_image as image',  'manufacturers.manufacturers_name as name', 'manufacturers_info.manufacturers_url as url', 'manufacturers_info.url_clicked', 'manufacturers_info.date_last_click as clik_date')
    ->get();
    $result['manufacturers'] = $manufacturers;
    return view("index", $title)->with('result', $result); }
```

my views:

```
{{ $manufacturer->name }}
```

help would be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: how are you calling your view?

Comment: try $manufacturers->name ... s to the end ...

Comment: Can you show how you pass data to the view? More at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: sorry i should have added that. this is the way i passed the data to my view 
 return view("index", $title)->with('result', $result);

Comment: Are you returning $result ? If the answer is yes then I assume $manufacturers is available in your view template and {{ $manufacturer->name }} in inside a loop block like @foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) ...

Comment: yes Oscar.. its in @foreach loop. still having error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're putting the manufacturers array in the $result and passing the $result then you have to reference it by $result in your view.

```
   $result['manufacturers'] = $manufacturers;
   return view("index", $title)->with('result', $result);
```

Something like...

```
   @foreach ($result['manufacturers'] as $manufacturer) 
     {{ $manufacturer->name }}
   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

in the Controller:

```
$result['manufacturers'] = $manufacturers;
return view('index', [
            $result => $result,
]);
```

in the view:

```
<ul>
   @foreach ($result['manufacturers'] as $manufacturer) 
       <li>{{ $manufacturer->name }} </li>
   @foreach
</ul>
```

Comment: still having error bro. i actually passed it to my views this way: 
return view("index", $title)->with('result', $result);